# Что произойдет, если свитч HP 5120 PoE сбросится на default?

Tags: сеть, hp, коммутатор

Если вышеуказанный свитч сбросился на default, то что произойдет?

1. Все интерфейсы будут выключены?
2. Он будет иметь какой либо ИП?
3. Можно ли его как нибудь настроить без помощи консольного кабеля?

Answer (score 2):

### 0. Если он вдруг сам сбросится на default - это повод обратиться в HP Support.

1. С большей вероятностью, порты будут administrative down (Выключены). Но это не факт, на некоторых прошивках наоборот, при сбросе открываются все порты.
2. Нет.
3. См выше. Нет.

Comment: На этой модели  (JG236A и подобные) - Порты с 1 по 24 или 48 будут в up, интерфейсы SFP и порты платы расширения, если таковые имеются, будут в adm down.